# At which layer of OSI model an ARP request is made by host computer?

Tags: arp

In order to get the MAC address of destination's computer, the host computer sends an ARP request. At which layer ARP request is made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [link layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_layer) as described in [ARP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) on wiki. It's really helpful to see packet structure by yourself, so I encourage you to install [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) on your PC, to start sniffing network and to ping non existing IP address in your subnet. Filtering by "arp" will show you something like this:

[image]